# Is possible initialization of property without Generic Methods of interface?

Tags: c#

Say there are interface and classes.

```
interface IPen<T> {...}

class PenModelA : IPen<ModelA> {...}
class PenModelAA : IPen<ModelA> {...}
class PenModelB : IPen<ModelB> {...}
class PenModelBA : IPen<ModelB> {...}
```

How can I define property without generic method of interface? Generic method will define later in constructor. One moment, the property must be global and I must have the opportunity to use it in whole class.

I want to do it like that.

```
class Qwerty
{
  public IPen<T> A {get; set;}

  public Qwerty()
  {
    if (...)
    {
      IPen<ModelA> A;
      A = new PenModelA();
    }
    else
    {
      IPen<ModelB> A;
      A = new PenModelB();
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

There are ModelA, ModelB.

```
class ModelA
{
   public int Z;
}

class ModelB
{
   public string Y;
   public bool L;
   public One L;
}

class One
{
   public bool QW;
}
```

Comment: Do you know `IPen<ModelA> A;` will make the outter `A` to be hidden, that is, the assigment statement would have no effect on it.

Comment: It probably won't work how you want it to, but try defining your pen interface as `IPen<out T>` (covariance). And pay attention to dcg's comment - you're redeclaring A within the scope of Qwerty, so it will only be assigned here.

Comment: @dcg Yes, I want that `public IPen<T> A` redefine to `IPen<ModelA> A` or `IPen<ModelB> A` in accordance with condition. This is example not working. It is for example. And don't know how can i do this feature. If this is possible at all.

Comment: @Kirill I don't really get what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @john Can you advice to me where i can find information about `<out T>`? I can't find it.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: @dcg I'm tring to achieve define `<T>` in code in accordance with condition and varable of `<T>` will be global and available in whole class Qwerty.

Comment: @john Me don't suit `class Qwerty<T>` because I don't want ever throw generic method up. In this solution I face to this problem on level up. And I have updated post. I added ModelA, ModelB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot just define `IPen<T>` without specifying what that `T` is. That leaves you with 2 possibilities.

1) Use common base class\interface for `T`. For example:

```
interface IPen<out T> where T : IModel {}
interface IModel {}
class PenModelA : IPen<ModelA> {}
class PenModelB : IPen<ModelB> {}
class ModelA : IModel {}
class ModelB : IModel {}
```

Here you say that `T` in `IPen` should implement `IModel` interface (could also be a base class, like `BaseModel`), and implement that intreface for your models. Put methods common to all models to that interface. Then you can do:

```
class Qwerty {
    public IPen<IModel> A { get; set; }

    public Qwerty() {
        if (true) {
            A = new PenModelA();
        }
        else {
            A = new PenModelB();
        }
    }
}
```

To be able to assign specific pens (like `PenModelA`) to `IPen<IModel>` - you need to make `T` covariant in `IPen` (`out` keyword like we did in the example above). That restricts how you can use `T` inside interface. Covariant types cannot be used as method arguments:

```
interface IPen<out T> where T : IModel {
    // NOT allowed
    void SetModel(T model);        
}
```

But can be used as return type:

```
interface IPen<out T> where T : IModel {
    // allowed
    T GetModel(T model);        
}
```

2) Define non-generic version of interface and inherit generic one from it:

```
 interface IPen {}
 inerface IPen<T> : IPen {}
```

Put all non-generic methods to non-generic interface and use like this:

```
class Qwerty {
    public IPen A { get; set; }

    public Qwerty() {
        if (true) {
            A = new PenModelA();
        }
        else {
            A = new PenModelB();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea with interface of generic method. I don't think about this. But one else problem. My classes ModelA and ModelB are hard combining in interface. They are different. I have update post. Please look. Is it possible, use this solution with different models?

Comment: @Kirill then you need to clarify what exactly you are going to do with `IPen<T> A` in class `Qwerty`. If you don't care what is `T` in `IPen` - then it's better to go with option 2 - use non-generic `IPen`.

Comment: Oh... I only now understood second solution, I still know c# not very well. Yes, this suit me full. :) Thanks.